# webpack | after bundel creation, $inject on function getting undefined

Tags: angularjs, webpack, modular

i have recently started a project and using webpack as build tool.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('appController', require('./src/appController'));
```

and my appcontroller.js looks like

```
'use strict';
var appController = function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'hello';
};
appController.$inject(['$scope']);
module.exports = appController;
```

bundel is being formed at desired location, problem is when i use the function.$inject for dependency injection, as i want my code to get uglify, i gets browser error when i runs my app

> appController.$inject is not a function

This is first time i'm experiencing the error as i'm using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

`$inject` is not a function, it's property. It should be:

```
appController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```